# MVC informing back when long request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering what might be the best give to the user info about what is processing on ther server when there is long request.

So far, I have only one idea which is, every few calculation on the server, save info what is done into db table, and quering this every second from client using ajax.

What do you think of this, or do you know better way ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe WebSockets will do this. Check http://www.websocket.org/echo.html [1](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

Comment: If you are going to use WebSockets, and since the original question mentions using MVC, I suggest going with [Asp.Net SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) since Microsoft did all the work of tightly integrating it with Asp.Net.

Answer (score -2):

In general your flow will look like that:
1. save to DB
2. show info to user.
again 1.
again 2.
again 1.
again 2…..

instead of that i would simply show to the user some message like "processing your data, please wait" and then simply made the transaction.

Comment: but in case some report which takes 60s to generate, and 10 different operation are calculating, it might be nice to show what server is doing currently, and this is my question.

Comment: in that case i would do it like you wrote :)